# 'gulp-browser-sync' is not in the npm registry

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

When I try to run `gulp` I am getting the following errors.

Can someone explain where I am going wrong?

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "gulp-browser-sync" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/gulp-browser-sync
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 'gulp-browser-sync' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'timber-bootstrap'
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\xampp\htdocs\wptest\wp-content\themes\timber-bootstrap\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: That means exactly what the error message says. There is not `gulp-browser-sync` package on [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com). What don't you understand about that?

Comment: Can you explain how I add 'gulp-browser-sync' in the npm registry? :-)

Comment: It's called [`browser-sync`](https://github.com/kmturley/timber-bootstrap/blob/c1b0f2ed0697c43bd3734b769832a70b88bf1b6a/gulpfile.js#L7).

Comment: @robertklep Fantastic - thank you. This has now resolved my issue. Please feel free to add this as an Answer :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved this by running:

`npm install browser-sync gulp --save-dev`